# Most Efficient Iron Golem Farm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have two ideas, the first one would be 2 chunks wide (18 blocks) and go 3 chunks back (24 blocks) that way they don't have to die before more spawn. Then they get pushed forward with ice to the lava

My second idea is I have 2 chunks wide, and 3 chunks tall, then fall down and get pushed into lava.  So it a lot more compact and takes up less space.

Which of the two designs are more efficient taking space and produce into consideration?

Comment: So... what are you asking? Are you asking which design is better? Also, do you have access to custom mob spawners?

Comment: Yea I am asking what design would be better, I will edit that in. And yes I have 2 iron golem spawners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though the second design would work better. As long as the spawners aren't within 9 blocks of each other, they should work at full speed. Tesselable, vertical designs are always my first choice, especially with my own Survival-built spawn traps. Just make sure that there are no blocks without water on them that the golems could get stuck on.

Comment: I was thinking about the dead center or the chunk, since it is towny I do have the exact chunks. So that will not be a problem.   My main question is where on the z axis in side the chunk

Comment: Chunk borders have no effect on mob spawners, except that they need to be in a loaded chunk for them to work.

Comment: Their is a mob limit per chunk, so in a way it dose. That why my plan is to have it spread out like that

Comment: Couldn't you simply put it in the spawn chunks of your world ? (Where a compass points where you have no bed). This way you have your spawner running 24/7. No need to care about mob limits (well not really) since it will be always running no matter where you are in the world.

Comment: @Jaconah no there isn't. There is a total mob cap which is calculated based on the number of loaded chunks.

Comment: @Karlyr I would love to, but it's on a server so I can't.